# Video Streaming Fails on IIS 8

Tags: windows-server-2012, fastcgi, iis-8, video-streaming

I am using FastCGI with IIS 8 on windows-server 2012. The server is hosting a Django based website. The website works fine until I stream the videos (which are saved in the media folder on the server and are webm files). FireFox does not render anything, it keeps on transferring data and in the end gives an error **"Video playback aborted due to network error"**. On chrome however, the video plays but for a few seconds and then stops. In the console I can see the error **"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"**.

I have the same application on heroku, which works fine. I don't seem to get what the problem is with my settings on the server.

p.s I think there is something to do with the Firewall. When the connection takes a long time, the firewall truncates it.